# Open sets containing closed set

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A,B$ be 2 disjoint closed sets in a metric spce $(X,d)$
I know that $A=\cap_{n\in \Bbb N}C_n$ where $C_n=\{x\in X:d(x,A)<1/n\}$ and $B=\cap_{n\in \Bbb N}D_n$ where $D_n=\{x\in X:d(x,B)<1/n\}$.

It seems right that $\exists n \in \Bbb N$ such that $C_n\cap D_n=\emptyset$.

My idea is to suppose not and build a sequence $x_n\in C_n\cap D_n\forall n\in \Bbb N$. But I got stuck at finding the contradiction.

Comment: I assume $C$ and $D$ are meant to be $C_n$ and $D_n$?

Comment: Thank you @BrandonduPreez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not right. Take for example $X = \mathbb R^2$ equipped with the euclidean metric, $A=\{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathbb R\}$ and $B = \{(x, 1/x) \mid x \neq 0\}$.

This is true if one of the subset is supposed to be compact though.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer! I have another question that how can I define a continuous function $f$ on $X$ with $f(x)=0$ on A and $f(x)=1$ on B? My original idea is to prove the question asked, then make the function value small gradually on the $C_n,D_n$. But since the statement is wrong, I have to find another way.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$